# Wordpress - searching for "ap" redirects me to the lost password page

Tags: php, wordpress

I just noticed this strange behavior on one of my Wordpress sites. The search function seems to be working perfectly fine for anything else. Redirection to "lost account" page happens only when I type "ap" in the search box.

Specifically, the URL after redirection is:

```
http://homeurl/lostpassword/?error=invalidkey
```

It is very strange for me because I don't recall doing anything that could cause this and it was discovered by an accident.

I do have a function in functions.php to modify the search process:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_search_query');
function alter_search_query($query) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_search() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_type');

        if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
            $query->set('post_type', sanitize_text_field($_GET['cat']));
        }
    }
}
```

Search form HTML:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="pull-right search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">

        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_query_var('s') ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="wyszukaj" required=required/>
        <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" />

</form>
```

I also have a custom search.php template in my theme folder but it doesn't really contain any logic apart from looping the search results.

I do not have any plugins which alter the search function. At least none that I know of.

What could be causing this? I need to know, as there could be more surprises like this one.

Comment: Could do with seeing some more code, do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the link to the site, I can post any problem-related code though. The thing is, I cannot think of any modifications that were made in this matter and the what I did not post here should be the standard Wordpress 3.8 code. Just tell me what you need.

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you post the search box HTML. What happens if you comment out your custom code?

Comment: I have added the HTML code. Also, I just noticed that commenting out my custom code prevents this from happening (the search now returns results) but it doesn't sort them the way I want to, so it has to be fixed.

Comment: Both of these are fine, but do you mean removing the add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_search_query') fixes it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51200/discussion-between-ptimson-and-pawel-duda)